# change a variable inside it without redefining the function

Tags: javascript

Friends
How, after defining a function, change a variable inside it without redefining the function.
For example, I have this function

```
 Data = function () {
    function n() {
            var n = this;
            this.same = function (n) {
            this.search = function (n, t, i, r) { ... }
            this.go = function (n, t) { ... }
            this.get = function (n, t) {... }
            this.run = function (n, t) { console.log("test") } //change this item
        }
    }
}()
```

And I want it to become the following function.

```
 Data = function () {
    function n() {
            var n = this;
            this.same= function (n) {
            this.search = function (n, t, i, r) { ... }
            this.go = function (n, t) { ... }
            this.get = function (n, t) {... }
            this.run = function (n, t) { alert("test ok") } // changed 
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: What are you allowed to change in the code and what not, if you cannot just redefine the function?

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `Data`, please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the other answer totally achieves what you want. If so, this might be a better alternative:

```js
var Data = function () {
  this.run = function (n, t) { console.log("test") } // change this later
  
  var dataSelf = this;
  this.n = function () {
      var n = this;
      this.same = function (n) { }
      this.search = function (n, t, i, r) { }
      this.go = function (n, t) { }
      this.get = function (n, t) { }
      this.run = dataSelf.run
  };
}

const en = new Data()
new en.n().run() // Logs "test"

en.run = function(n, t) { alert("test ok"); }
new en.n().run() // Alerts "test ok"
```